# Disable context menu based on the value of check box in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I have a grid and a context menu on that.Now I have another toggle button which will perform some other activity.

Now I want these two behaviors

- when the toggle button is checked then if user press right click, the context menu should not come but
- when the toggle button is not checked than if user perform right click, the context menu should come on the screen.

I have written booltoVisibility converter it is working fine.

```
<ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding RunViewModel.PlayModel.Active,Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">

public class BoolToVisibilityConverter:IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (value!=null)
        {
            visibility = (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return visibility;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

RunViewModel.PlayModel.Active is bound with the IsChecked of the toggle button.

Now the problem is that,
When the button is checked and I do right click then it works fine but when the uncheck the toggle button it is comming back in the screen, I have made the binding oneWay still the problem is there.

can anyone help me out..!!

Comment: *I have written booltoVisibility converter*... why? What's wrong with the built in [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.PlayModel.Active, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=Self}}"
```

Comment: Heya, this answer is low on content -it'd be great if you could explain how your solution is different and why it solves the problem. Don't forget that newbies come here all the time and like to know how your fix solves the problem... so they can learn a thing from you :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have much more luck trying to do this using a `DataTrigger` rather than an `IConverter`. Try this code, which sets the `Button.ContextMenu` to `null` when the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property value is `True`:

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Content="Check me" Width="100" Height="25" 
        Margin="0,60,0,0" />
    <Button Content="Click me" Margin="0" Width="100" Height="25">
        <Button.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Option 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Option 2" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.Resources>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                        ElementName=ToggleButton}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```